# What does "libros cuyas páginas aprendí a cortar, para no comprobar, meses después, que estaban intactos" mean?

Tags: interpretación

In "El Aleph", Borges states that upon visiting Beatriz parents:

> No estaría obligado, como otras veces, a justificar mi presencia con
>   módicas ofrendas de libros: libros cuyas páginas, finalmente, aprendí
>   a cortar, para no comprobar, meses después, que estaban intactos.

Which has been translated as:

> I would not be forced, as in the past, to justify my presence with
>   modest offerings of books — books whose pages I finally learned to cut
>   beforehand, so as not to find out, months later, that they lay around
>   unopened.

Am I the only one who finds this utterly confusing? Did he open the books months later or not?

Comment: asides from the correct answer, it's useful to know that the last word, "intactos" could have perhaps been better translated as "untouched", thus avoiding some of the confusion.

Comment: Indeed the translation is unnecesarily imprecise, if not wrong. (You can open a book with the pages uncut. You just can't read the pages facing in.)

Comment: These are called "uncut or untrimmed leaves" in English. Read about it here: https://collation.folger.edu/2016/08/uncut-unopened-untrimmed-uh-oh//books whose leaves I finally learned to cut so as not to have to see months later  they hadn't been.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In those days books had pages which had not been cut from their original format. If he gave someone a book with uncut pages and then, months later, found the pages still uncut he would know they had never read it. To avoid this disappointment he learned to cut the pages before giving them the books. So it is not Borges who did not open them months later but the people to whom he gave them.

The whole process of printing the larger sheets is called imposition in English and *imposición* as this [wikepedia article](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imposici%C3%B3n) shows with a helpful diagram of how to do it.

Comment: I have very occasionally had the experience of reading a book where all but a small number of the pages had been cut.  I wonder if that was the case here, or if the reader was responsible for cutting *all* the pages?

Comment: I doubt that. I think he is saying he learned to cut them so he would not have to deal with them uncut months  later.

Answer (score 0):

**Sobre los libros Intonsos en el Aleph de Borges**

Hola

En este pasaje Borges se refiere a un tipo de libros que en Español, decimos "Intonsos".

El término "Intonso" viene de "Tonsura" que es el inicial ó primer grado sacerdotal. Cuando el novicio accedía a ese grado, el obispo cortaba ceremonialmente el pelo, cortando al cero la parte superior de la cabeza en forma redondeada. La "calva" se llama tonsura que es por la que se accedía a esa primera dignidad sacerdotal. Así "estar intonso" es no tener esa dignidad y por tanto no tener ese corte. Por tanto, "intonso" viene de ahí, de no estar aún cortado ó medio-intonso, de no haberse cortado de forma correcta.

Otra voz es "desbarbar un libro", cortar, quitar las rebabas de algo, dejar los cortes limpios, es decir, guillotinar los bordes de las hojas de tal forma que quedan igualados. Por tanto, existen libros "sin desbarbar", en los que los bordes de las hojas son irregulares dejados tal cual después del proceso de fabricación del papel ó como si hubieran sido cortados a mano.

Antiguamente, cuando el proceso era casi totalmente artesanal, los pliegos se dejaban en muchos casos "intonsos", es decir, sin cortar ó sin cortar las barbas, era pues el propio lector el que debía realizar esta operación y abrir los bordes que quedaban unidos en las páginas a medida que iba avanzando en la lectura. No cortar los bordes significaba que no se había abierto la página, pues es imposible si antes no se "desbarban" y por tanto, por esta sencilla regla, se sabia que libros habían sido leídos y cuales no.

---

Parte técnica sobre los pliegos...

Los pliego forman las hojas de papel, de un solo pliego salen varias páginas, normalmente para estos casos se compra un tamaño grande con el fin de tener menos costes. Así la imprenta imprimía sobre ellos varias páginas y en distintas orientaciones, posteriormente cuando se doblaba y manipulaba el pliego salían cuatro páginas debidamente orientadas. Por eso en los libros y revistas, normalmente hay que contar de cuatro en cuatro, depende del tamaño y de los dobleces que se hagan al pliego, depende si es un A5, A4....dos dobleces cuatro hojas, tres dobleces ocho hojas...

Los pliegos doblados se encuadernan y se guillotinan los bordes de las hojas ya que  son las dobleces las que quedan en los bordes. Si esta operación no se realiza, es decir, no se guillotina o no se hace correctamente, tenemos un libro INTONSO.

---

El secreto para entender este pasaje esta en atender a las comas.

"No estaría obligado, como otras veces, a justificar mi presencia con módicas ofrendas de libros: libros cuyas páginas, finalmente, aprendí a cortar, para no comprobar, meses después, que estaban intactos."

A groso modo este sería el resumen del significado:

- "No estaría obligado, como otras veces, a justificar mi presencia con módicas ofrendas de libros:" - "*No volvería a prestar más libros*".
- "libros cuyas páginas, finalmente, aprendí a cortar," - "*se refiere a este tipo de libros, libros intonsos*".
- "para no comprobar, meses después," - "*para no tener la decepción cuando me los devolvieran,*".
- "que estaban intactos." - "*que estaban sin leer*".

Diego M.